# What type of bike does this text refer to?

Tags: shopping

While looking up things for answering another question, I found that USA has a separate import duty category for "Bicycles having a front wheel exceeding 55 cm but not exceeding 63.5 cm in diameter and a rear wheel exceeding 63.5 cm in diameter, weighing less than 16.3 kg complete without accessories and not designed for use with tires having a cross-sectional diameter exceeding 4.13 cm, valued $200 or more each". Does this refer to an existing type of bicycle, and what is it?

As far as I know, the largest common rim size is exactly 63.5 cm, but I have no idea if tire is in included in the number.

Comment: There were at one time bicycles produced for women that more or less matched this description.  I'm thinking that Terry sold these, before they switched to being mainly a seat and clothing manufacturer.  https://www.naomida.com/play/stuff/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/CIMG4278.jpg

Comment: The rear wheel looks like standard 622mm

Comment: I *think* these customs categories are defined internationally, hence the metric units. But as the rear wheel must be strictly larger than the front, it's nothing common

Comment: @ojs - It's talking about the wheel size, not the rim size.  So anything larger than 25 inches for the rear -- 26 inch, 27 inch, 700c, et al.  With a front tire larger than 21 inches but smaller than 25 (eg, 24 inch).

Comment: I think it's safe to assume they mean outer diameter including the tire and it's covering 80s-90s style time trial bikes.  (This is the same market that invented 5 different sizes of 26" wheel after all....)

Comment: Common says the size might refer to wheel as in commonly used in bicycle context: the combination of rim, spokes and hub. Or tire. Or fairing (though my sense doesn't stretch to this). Or some entirely non-physical entity as with inch sizes. Any source would be nice.

Comment: Published customs ruling referring to OD as 'wheel size'? : https://www.customsmobile.com/rulings/docview?doc_id=NY%20882137&highlight=8712.00.35%2A  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least some evidence findable via google that 'Wheel size' here is interpreted with the vernacular 'outer diameter of the tire' rather than the bead seat diameter.

e.g., [a common 26" Mountain Bike from the era is described as having '66.4 cm wheels'](https://www.customsmobile.com/rulings/docview?doc_id=NY%20882137&highlight=8712.00.35%2A) not 57.1 or whatever they would have been.

> Model ATB-S is the Rebel 10 speed mountain bicycle. The frame size is
>   48.26 centimeters (19 inches) and the wheels size is 66.4 x 5.397 centimeters (26 x 2.125 inches). This bicycle weighs 17.3 kilograms.

If we accept they mean the vernacular outer diameter "wheel size" then it's simply describing the Time Trial 'Funny Bike' that was popular 30-40 years ago.

Comment: So its a tax on importing foreign brands of competitive time trial bikes like the pinarello sword ?

Comment: This category has actually one of the lower taxes.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that they just take the inch size that doesn't correspond to any physical dimension at face value and convert it to millimeters.

Comment: It's not entirely absurd that it corresponds to the way the manufacturers were actually labeling the product!  e.g., "26 Inch Wheels"

Comment: @Criggie looks more like a bureaucratic hack to add an item that covered the bikes when they started showing up because they wouldn't fit in an existing category the way the others were structured.  Might have a low rate cause nobody ever bothered to raise it cause nobody makes them any more.

Comment: @Affe I just assumed it was created before 1984 to nab team sports bikes coming to the country for the LA olympics, and that it would be a high rate.     This is an interesting question.